# Inserts with Mongoengine work only from shell, but not from Django view

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am having strange situation - creating some Mongoengine object from Django shell is successful, but creating the same object from Django view looks like successful but without any data appeared in MongoDB. I.e. the same code like that -

```
from myapp.mongomodels import MyModel

m = MyModel(a=1, b=2, c=3)
m.save()
```

produces new object inserted into MongoDB when running from `manage.py shell`, and produces nothing when running from Django view. I have traced the code and I am seeing `mongoengine.Document.save()` method is running correctly without any exceptions.

Looks like I've missed something obvious.

Will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Are the `settings` the same?  Are they using the same database?  Please include evidence that the settings are the same.

Comment: Aah seems I've found where is the problem. I am assigning a primary key value to to object before saving it, and pymongo thinks this is an update, but not insert. However, it is still strange this code works from shell and does not work from Django view. Will reply when I fix the problem.

Comment: You should provide this an an answer to your question.   Other people will have this problem.

Comment: `manage.py` shell should use the same settings as `manage.py runserver`. I believe the settings are the same due to I am seeing MongoDB update query (with parameters exactly the same I've called from the view) executed while opening the web page with my test view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that but force the save using:

```
from myapp.mongomodels import MyModel

m = MyModel(a=1, b=2, c=3)
m.save(force_insert=True)
```

Comment: How can identical code work in the shell but not in a view?  

I am having this problem, but I am attempting to insert a new document into a list on an existing document.

Comment: Holy wow.  It appears that this bug occurs if you use quotes to reference a not yet defined model in your EmbeddedDocumentField within a ListField.

Comment: Not sure I follow - can you pastie an example?

Answer (score 0):

As I've told before, the problem was in that I am assigning a primary key value BEFORE saving.

I have a system with some data stored in MySQL and some corresponding data stored in MongoDB. MySQL record is created first, related MongoDB record is created right after MySQL record, with the same primary key value. Thus, pymongo thinks thas this is update request instead of insert request, and no record is inserted at all.